# Link de arquivo para visualização / download / impressão

Tags: html

### Cenário

Tenho uma lista de **arquivos** gerada dinamicamente, e gostaria de ter 3 opções:

- **Abrir**: exibir no navegador (caso seja PDF, JPG, etc);
- **Download**: fazer o download direto;
- **Imprimir**: enviar **direto para impressora padrão**.

---

### O que consegui

**Visualizar** com `target="_blank` na tag `<a>`:

```
<td><a href="files/100-1533649017.pdf" target="_blank">MeuArquivo.pdf</a></td>
```

**Download** com `download` na tag `<a>`:

```
<td><a href="files/100-1533649017.pdf" download>MeuArquivo.pdf</a></td>
```

---

#### Dúvidas

- De imediato, não encontrei para **enviar direto a impressora**, existe forma nativa do HTML para isso?
- Caso não exista forma nativa HTML, quais alternativas?
- Existe **outra forma**, da que utilizei, para **visualizar**?
- Existe **outra forma**, da que utilizei, para **download**?

Comment: Para casos de imprimir da uma olhada nesse link: [LInk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript)

Comment: @Wesleyaraujo Agradeço a ajuda, mas queria direto no HTML, e também não só PDF, tenho XML, JPG, RAR, etc ✌️

Comment: Não sei se é possível com HTML puro. Creio que pelo menos tenha que colocar atributo do tipo "onclick(//codigo JS)" para ter resultado no que deseja

Answer (score -1):

Não tem como enviar um arquivo para impressão, mas o que se pode fazer é exibir o conteúdo desse arquivo em uma tela e executar o comando de javascript para impressão, conforme citado anteriormente. Após esse comando fechar essa tela com window.close. Fica "quase" a mesma coisa. Talvez seja possível fazer isso dentro de um iframe invisível.